# bash script to windows cmd, with nested command

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, curl

I am doing this curl command successfully in bash console to retrieve data from a rest resource :

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-content: test_content" -H "X-Public: public_key" -H "X-Hash: $(printf "testcompany1" | openssl sha256 -hmac "secret_key" | sed "s/^.* //" | tr -d "\n")" -X GET http://192.168.100.20/rest/v01/customer/csv > /home/user/customer.csv
```

What I want to do is to use this in a windows cmd shell. Cygwin and curl is installed. So I have tracked it down to this puzzling me, the hmac hashing, done as a nested command in my script using $(command) :

```
$(printf "testcompany1" | openssl sha256 -hmac "secret_key" | sed "s/^.* //" | tr -d "\n")
```

How do I get a windows shell cmd recognize this ? Or is there another smarter approach in windows to get rest data with hmac auth ?

Comment: Running : printf "testcompany1" | openssl sha256 -hmac "secret_key" | sed "s/^.* //" | tr -d "\n" and inserting the hash in X-hash returns the expected result. FYI

Comment: I wouldn't start translating bash into Windows command shell even if one pays me a lot of money. While there is a variation of the SET command, which allows you to stuff the standard output of a command into an environment variable, you would run sooner or later into new problems. Since you have Cygwin installed anyway, why not writing the whole thing as a script in bash/zsh/ruby/perl/whateveryoulike, and then write a tiny BATCH-wrapper around it?

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion. I've made a batch file. This one I can call from libreoffice as first intended.

Answer (score 0):

I split the bash oneliner up i chunks in a batch file like this :

```
echo off
set content=content
set secret=secret_key
printf %content% | openssl sha256 -hmac %secret% | sed "s/^.* //" | tr -d "\n" > hash.txt
set /p hash=< hash.txt
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-content: %content%" -H "X-Public: public_key -H "X-Hash: %hash%" -X GET http://192.168.100.20/rest/v01/customer/csv > out.csv
```

The printf command was very picky regarding generating the correct hash value, so I send it to a file first, and back again.